# month attribute from csv datetime data

Tags: python, datetime

I have a csv file with weather parameter rain and datetime in m/d/y hh:mm:ss.

I used the following code and see the link for the csv file [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt3a8hewkv36aai/example_s.csv?dl=0):

Now i want to change the dates to datetime in python. How could I do that? I hope my question is clear now

```
import csv

with open('example_s.csv') as csvfile:
     readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

     for row in readCSV:

         row_2 = row[2]

         print(row_2)
```

Comment: Please fix python indent.

Comment: **Don't** use code images, show the relevant code as text! How do you think, `csv` has `type datetime` data? How do you think, a `str` object has a attribute `month`? [Edit] your Question and explain in deatail.

Comment: @stovfl ...i have edited my question..hope i can get some information from you guys

Comment: **Again**, don't use images. [Edit] your Question and show **3 lines** from your CSV as text, best displayed if you format i as code. I see no attemp *"to change the dates to datetime"* read about [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer on the request. You have data format that is not recognizable by `datetime` libarary for the time of writing this post.

You need to create your own utility function, huckish solution:

```
def data_converter(date):
    subdates = date.split('/')
    if len(subdates[0]) == 1:
        subdates[0] = "0" + subdates[0]
    if len(subdates[1]) == 1:
        subdates[1] = "0" + subdates[1]
    return "/".join(subdates)
```

Input format would be `mm/dd/yy/ hh:mm:ss`:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('10/01/80/ 13:10:15', '%m/%d/%y/ %H:%M:%S')
```

Now, having ugly utility function and parser for the date you have all arsenal to create datetime in Python. You need to think and combine pieces together.

For more details take a look on documentation [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) that should answer on some your questions.